# PHP: add external pdf page to generated pdf using mPDF

Tags: php, pdf, mpdf

I'am using mPDF to generate the first page of a pdf using a template file, and I need to add an external (single paged) pdf file to the second page.

For that I download the external pdf file to /tmp directory and I use this code found in mPDF github manual (https://mpdf.github.io):

```
$loPdf->SetImportUse();
// getOriginInvoice returns the path of the tmp pdf file downloaded
$lsFile = $this->getOriginInvoice($loBill);
if (!empty($lsFile)) {
    $liNbpages = $loPdf->SetSourceFile($lsFile);
    for ($liPage = 1; $liPage <= $liNbpages; $liPage++) {
        $loPdf->UseTemplate($loPdf->ImportPage($liPage));
    }
}
$loPdf->Output('/data/tmp/test.pdf');
```

After running this code the test.pdf file contains only the first generated page !

I tried to create a new pdf file and import the external file and it works,  but when I try to add the pdf file to the generated one it doesn't work !

So that's why I need your help guys, I tried all the solutions that I found !!

Comment: Please tell us what you have alright tried, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The only working solution I found is to Output the first generated page to a tmp file and then merge with the other pdf .. I think mPDF can't handle creation and mergin at the same time so I had to do it separately !

Comment: Do you have an example?